# Iptables: unrecognized service

Tags: services, ufw

Why below command works correctly:

```
sudo iptables-save
```

But below command has error: `iptable: unrecognized service`

```
sudo service iptables start
```

An also I install iptables and did below commands properly:

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save
service ufw start
```

Answer (score 1):

As you added the tag `ufw` i'm guessing you are using the default ubuntu firewall manager `ufw` and not `iptables` you can disable the `ufw` firewall with

```
sudo ufw disable
```

`ufw` has an excellent manual you can access it with `man ufw`

Comment: Excuse me I edited my question.